# jQuery Ideas for Featured Article on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes

I'm trying to do this in Wordpress: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXWUO.png

Basically there are six 'featured' articles with their respective thumbnails on the right. When I click on the thumbnail on the right, I want it to appear bigger in the 'main' image spot, swapping the thumbnail with what was there previously. Can you guys recommend a simple way to do this- any plugins, etc?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: This won't be difficult, but providing a concise answer without any current markup will be. what's the identifier for each of those images? What's the identifier for the "big" image?

Comment: The big image is a div with id "mainstory" and I guess the others can be divs with class "feature" inside of a larger, grouping div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples) it offers some nice feature out of the box and is easy to use, once you download it you just do this to include it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding bootstrap will find you resolve. If I'm understanding correctly, you want to replace the large image with the image that was clicked on. When that happens, you also want to replace the thumbnail you clicked on with the image that is `currently the mainimage`, however, use a thumbnail.

```
$('.feature').click(function(){
    /* The SRC of the image you want to use as the mainimage */
    var newImg = $(this).find('img').prop('src');

    /* The SRC of the mainimage you want to use as the new featured image */
    var oldImg = $('#mainstory').find('img').prop('src');

    /* Change the SRC of the current #mainstory image to the one from the featured image */
    $('#mainstory').find('img').prop('src', newImg);

    /* Change the SRC of the clicked featured image to the SRC from the mainimage
    $(this).find('img').prop('src', oldImg);
});
```

Alternatively, you can supply certain heights/widths to get the correct size. If you didn't create the image with multiple sizes, you can by using [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

Comment: This would help change the pictures, but not the links associated with the pictures.